# Strange bug during Date Calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created an iOS app that compares various date ranges and returns the overlap of days between the ranges. The app is working as intended, but when I hit the "Calculate" button in the user interface of the simulator, the console returns the following text (excerpt):

```
 *** -[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: fromDate cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil fromDate?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
```

The app does not crash, nor does Xcode detect any issues. Still, I would rather not ignore this. Does anyone know what is going on? Here is my code:

```
NSDate *overlapFrom12_range1 = [range1Start laterDate:startdate1];
    NSDate *overlapTo12_range1   = [range1End earlierDate:enddate2];


    NSInteger days12_range1;
    if ([overlapFrom12_range1 compare:overlapTo12_range1] > 0)
    {

        days12_range1 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:overlapFrom12_range1 toDate:overlapTo12_range1 options:0];
        days12_range1 = [comp day] +1;
    }
```

---

I added your suggestion to my code like so:

```
 NSInteger days12_range1;


    if ([overlapFrom12_range1 compare:overlapTo12_range1] > 0)
    {

        days12_range1 = 0;

    }
        else
    {
        if ([date1.text length] > 0 && [date2.text length] > 0)
        {

            NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:overlapFrom12_range1 toDate:overlapTo12_range1 options:0];
            days12_range1 = [comp day] +1;
        }
    }
```

However, the error still occurs... only if the date textfields are empty. Am I using the code snippet the wrong way?

BTW, here is the "backtrace" where the error occurs:

> (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x01cb0c04 -[**NSCFCalendar
>   components:fromDate:toDate:options:] + 84     1   App
>
>   0x00004de6 -[ViewController calculate] + 598  2   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x010f2705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77    3 
>   UIKit                               0x000262c0 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96    4   UIKit
>
>   0x00026258 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] +
>   61    5   UIKit                               0x000e7021 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66     6   UIKit
>
>   0x000e757f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   578   7   UIKit                               0x000e66e8 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546    8   UIKit
>
>   0x00055cef -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846    9   UIKit
>
>   0x00055f02 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273   10  UIKit
>
>   0x00033d4a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436  11  UIKit
>
>   0x00025698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874   12  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x01bfcdf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339     13  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x01bfcad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46   14  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x01c16bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 53  15  CoreFoundation                      0x01c16962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146   16  CoreFoundation                      0x01c47bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118    17  CoreFoundation
>   0x01c46f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x01c46e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   19  GraphicsServices
>   0x01bfb7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88   20  GraphicsServices
>   0x01bfb668 GSEventRun + 104   21  UIKit
>   0x00022ffc UIApplicationMain + 1211   22  App
>   0x00001e5d main + 141     23  App
>   0x00001d85 start + 53 )

UPDATE:

Ok, I did some extensive searching in my code, and finally, with NSLog, I was able to pinpoint the affected area. Here is the code that is causing the trouble:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; //allocate and initialize dateformatter1
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; //set date format using dateformatter1
NSDate *startdate1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: date1.text]; //set startdate

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; //allocate and initialize dateformatter2
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; //set date format using dateformatter2
NSDate *enddate2 = [dateFormatter2 dateFromString: date2.text]; //set enddate



    int days12 = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit                                                   fromDate:startdate1 toDate:enddate2 options:0] day] + 1;


    result12.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", days12];



NSLog (@"Startdate1 is %@ and Enddate2 is %@.", startdate1, enddate2);
```

NSLog shows that both startdate1 and enddate2 are (null). I would create an if-statement to only calculate days12 (and result12) if startdate1 and enddate2 > 0, but I have to use the date12 variable later on, so it did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: So, does overlapFrom12_range1 have a value?  Did you NSLog it?

Comment: Wow, I am so amazed and impressed with the error message, I had to tweet it and this question!

Comment: Btw. the code looks like my answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671078/overlap-of-a-date-range-with-other-date-ranges, so you could also have responded to that if there is a problem (or accept the answer if there is no problem).

Comment: Yes, it is your answer. Thanks! I will check to see if the above duplicate will work for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. Here is how I fixed it:

```
int days12;

    if ([value1 length] == 0)
    {
        days12 = 0;
        result12.text= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", days12];
    }
    else
    {
        days12 = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit                                                   fromDate:startdate1 toDate:enddate2 options:0] day] + 1;

        result12.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", days12];
    }
```

Thanks for helping!